# How can I read a text file with 200 lines of text, and identify identical string values?

Tags: php

I have a text file that contains 200 lines of text. How can I compare each line of text and identify the same values with PHP. Is that even possible?
Can I convert the lines to XML format?
Can I convert the text file to HTML and append the duplicate values to an un-ordered list?

Comment: Are you looking for duplicate lines or for duplicate inside the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to make an array of duplicate lines?  If so, you could use something like this:

```
<?php

/* load the file as an array of lines */
$lines = file('myfile');

/* put them in sorted order */
sort($lines);

/* loop over each line comparing it to the previous, to determine if it is a dup */
$last_line = null;
$duplicates = array();
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
  /* only add it to the duplicates array if it is not already there */
  if (strcmp($line, $last_line) == 0 && ! in_array($line, $duplicates))
  {
    $duplicates[] = $line;
  }
  $last_line = $line;
}

/* view the duplicates */
var_dump($duplicates);
?>
```

Comment: well, you was faster :/ Your is better, I think, though

Comment: Note that if you just want to eliminate duplicates from the file, you can also use array_unique.

Comment: @RPM - you would array_unique($lines); in place of `sort` and be done with it.

Comment: @Brand Horsley - The end result was NULL

Comment: @RPM - You should modify your question or post a new one if you have new issues.  $lines = array_unique($lines); should get rid of all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer you one question, first: Yes, you can. I'm tired so I'll sholl you just messy and unusable code in production case

```
$lines = file("file.txt");
sort($lines);

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    if (in_array($line, $lines) && !in_array($line, $dupes))
    {
       $dupes[] = $line;
    }
}

print_r($dupes);
```

Comment: why do you sort the lines and then use in_array?  in_array does not know it is sorted for bsearching, seems like wasted cpu cycles.